# Processing response in KRL

Tags: krl

I'm sending a request to google via their API using KRL and this is the literal response I am getting back from them:

```
handleResponse({ "data": { "responses": [ { "response": "successful" } ] } } );
```

How do you recommend I process this via pick as it is not 'valid' JSON syntax?  It contains valid JSON syntax, but as a whole is not valid. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which API? Google has a few.... :)

Comment: Which method of the translate API? Can you share your request code? The API has an option for using JSONP or returning raw JSON.

Comment: Let us know if your question has been answered by accepting an answer, otherwise give more details on what's not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: After looking at the Google translate API it looks like the JSONP callback parameter is optional. Don't specify a callback and you will no longer have this issue. : )

http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/using_rest.html#WorkingResults

**Better option:**

If you can, specify in your call to the google API that there be no callback function. If you can just request plain JSON instead of JSONP you can just use the pick operator.

**Not so better option:**

If the API only returns JSONP then you can do a regex replace to remove the padding from the JSON which will then allow you to use the pick operator.

What you'll need:

- Convert returned JSONP into a string using beesting or encode function
- [Replace function](http://docs.kynetx.com/docs/Replace)
- [Decode function](http://docs.kynetx.com/docs/Decode)
- [Pick operator](http://docs.kynetx.com/docs/Pick)

Full app example:

```
ruleset a60x494 {
  meta {
    name "jsonp-to-json-test"
    description <<
      jsonp-to-json-test
    >>
    author "Mike Grace"
    logging on
  }

  global {
    returnedJsonpAsString = 'handleResponse({ "data": { "responses": [ { "response": "successful" } ] } } );';
    datasource googleApi <- "blah blah blah";
  }

  rule fix_jsonp_to_json {
    select when pageview ".*"
    pre {
      cleanJson = returnedJsonpAsString.replace(re/^.*\((.*)\);/,"$1");
      response = cleanJson.decode().pick("$..response");
    }
    {
      notify("Response",response) with sticky = true;
      emit <|
        console.log(returnedJsonp);
        console.log(cleanJson);
      |>;
    }
  }
}
```